# How to access only one element within a nested json file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, azure, nested

I have this json file which has this data in it:

```
{   "language": "en",   "textAngle": 0,   "orientation": "Up",   "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "21,16,304,451",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "28,16,288,41",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "28,16,288,41",
              "text": "NOTHING"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "27,66,283,52",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "27,66,283,52",
              "text": "EXISTS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "27,128,292,49",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "27,128,292,49",
              "text": "EXCEPT"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "24,188,292,54",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "24,188,292,54",
              "text": "ATOMS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "22,253,297,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "22,253,105,32",
              "text": "AND"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "144,253,175,32",
              "text": "EMPTY"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "21,298,304,60",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "21,298,304,60",
              "text": "SPACE."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "26,387,294,37",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "26,387,210,37",
              "text": "Everything"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "249,389,71,27",
              "text": "else"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "127,431,198,36",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "127,431,31,29",
              "text": "is"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "172,431,153,36",
              "text": "opinion."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }   ] }
```

I've tried different methods, even with jQuery and I can't get ONLY the TEXT values from the above json file contents. Then I want to concatenate all the text values into a single string and have a counter to count all the words found as "TEXT".

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: add your attempt no one is going to write for you whole code and that too for free.

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this (I have not tested this but it should get your started on the right path):

Suppose the above structure is stored in the data object below:

```
var textArray = [];

if (data.hasOwnProperty("regions") && $.isArray(data.regions)) {
    var regions = data.regions;

    if (regions.hasOwnProperty("lines") && $.isArray(regions.lines)) {
        var lines = regions.lines;

        $.each(lines, function(i, line) {
            if (line.hasOwnProperty("words") && $.isArray(line.words)) {
                $.each(line.words, function(j, word) {
                    if (word.hasOwnProperty("text") && word.text) {
                        textArray.push(word.text);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At the end of this code, textArray should contain all of the "text" items in the JSON structure.